# Why can't I ping db from a unix machine on windows?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, proxy, unix

I have a windows machine, with ubuntu on it, where I run docker, in which there is a container I need to connect to db. But the problem is already between windows and ubuntu.

If I ping the db from windows, it does answer.

If I ping the db from ubuntu, it does not.

I tried on ubuntu with and without a proxy, and in neither case works.

If I curl google.com with the proxy on ubuntu, it answers. Without no.

when I try to ping from windows

```
ping 172.17.23.96
Pinging 172.17.23.96 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 172.17.23.96: bytes=32 time=21ms TTL=250
Reply from 172.17.23.96: bytes=32 time=19ms TTL=250
Reply from 172.17.23.96: bytes=32 time=18ms TTL=250
Reply from 172.17.23.96: bytes=32 time=18ms TTL=250

Ping statistics for 172.17.23.96:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 18ms, Maximum = 21ms, Average = 19ms
```

when I try to ping from ubuntu with proxy

```
$ ping 172.17.23.96
PING 172.17.23.96 (172.17.23.96) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 172.17.0.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 172.17.0.1 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 172.17.0.1 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- 172.17.23.96 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 4148ms
pipe 4
```

when I try to ping from ubuntu without proxy

```
$ export http_proxy=
$ ping 172.17.23.96
PING 172.17.23.96 (172.17.23.96) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 172.17.0.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 172.17.0.1 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 172.17.0.1 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- 172.17.23.96 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 4147ms
pipe 4
```

And I tried to connect to google from ubuntu

```
$ echo $http_proxy
http://host.internal:7070

$ curl http://google.com
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.com/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>

$ export http_proxy=
$ curl http://google.com
curl: (7) Failed to connect to google.com port 80: Connection refused
```

The following is the ipconfig of windows

```
ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Ethernet 3:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::1e9:9f33:79e7:cf08%2
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.184.146.37
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.184.146.38

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : bansel.it

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 9:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 10:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Mobile Broadband adapter Cellular:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : station
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::d00b:62bb:1184:f88e%30
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.14
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (WSL):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::1d8b:c0ca:b2f1:49e3%80
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.25.160.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

And this from ubuntu

```
$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 82:57:4f:bf:b8:64 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: dummy0: <BROADCAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 2a:bd:b5:2f:cd:1c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: tunl0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ipip 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
5: sit0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/sit 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
6: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:15:5d:14:3b:eb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.25.173.123/20 brd 172.25.175.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::215:5dff:fe14:3beb/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 02:50:00:00:00:01 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.67.3/24 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::50:ff:fe00:1/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
8: docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 02:42:19:24:aa:7d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:19ff:fe24:aa7d/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
14: vethe8ad906@if13: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master docker0 state UP group default
    link/ether fe:88:c4:c3:06:d1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet6 fe80::fc88:c4ff:fec3:6d1/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: Ping does not use HTTP proxies. It does not use HTTP. // I’m not entirely sure about your (virtual) network structure, but you probably have conflicting subnets somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

me!
After so much tries, I did

```
 wsl --unregister wsl-vpnkit
```

Then, downloaded it and reinstalled,

```
 wsl --import wsl-vpnkit $env:USERPROFILE\wsl-vpnkit wsl-vpnkit.tar.gz --version 2
```

And it worked!